# Вставка json со стороннего ресурса

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, json

Здравствуйте.
Подскажите пожалуйста, возможно-ли сделать запись данных из json который находится тут - https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/pubinfo?jsonp=success&exchange&coursid=5
к себе в таблицу?
Если да, то подскажите как или дайте ссылку на литературу. Буду весьма признателен.

Comment: Вывожу это всё таким способом:

<div id="out"></div>
<script>function success(data){
  data = data.find(e => e.ccy == "EUR" && e.base_ccy == "UAH");
  document.querySelector("#out").innerHTML = `Евро к гривне <br>Покупка:  ${data.buy}<br>Продажа: ${data.sale}`
}</script>
<script src="https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/pubinfo?jsonp=success&exchange&coursid=5"></script>

Comment: <div id="out1"></div>
<script>function success(data){
  data = data.find(u => u.ccy == "USD" && u.base_ccy == "UAH");
  document.querySelector("#out1").innerHTML = `Доллар к гривне <br>Покупка:  ${data.buy}<br>Продажа: ${data.sale}`
}</script>
<script src="https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/pubinfo?jsonp=success&exchange&coursid=5"></script>


Подскажите как объединить это в один запрос и сделать запись в мою бд?